# after update the table insert data like arrays

Tags: postgresql

I have `two tables`

```
Table A
col1        col2         col3

Table B  
table_name        column_name        new_value     old_value
```

if any update happened  on `table A` it will insert the data on `table B`

the output of table B is==>

```
    table_name         column_name         new_value             old_value
 ----------------     ------------------  --------------        -----------
      A                  {col1}   
      A                  {col1,col2}        {col1.new_value,      {col1.old_value,
                                             col2.new_value}       col2.old_value},
```

so anyone can tell me how to capture the column_names and it store data target table like arrays

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use Trigger Function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_history()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$ 
     DECLARE col_name VARCHAR[]; 
     DECLARE od_value VARCHAR[]; 
     DECLARE ne_value VARCHAR[]; 
     DECLARE each_column RECORD; 
     DECLARE each_entity RECORD; 
     DECLARE column_name VARCHAR; 
     DECLARE old_value VARCHAR; 
     DECLARE new_value VARCHAR; 

     FOR each_column IN 
          select c.column_name  --- Get the all column names in affected table 
          from information_schema.columns c 
       where(table_name = tg_relname And c.TABLE_SCHEMA = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA)
           LOOP 
           FOR each_entity IN --- Its used to get old and new columns value 
       EXECUTE 'SELECT text((' || quote_literal(OLD.*) || '::"' || tg_table_schema || '"."' || tg_relname || '")."'  || each_column.column_name || '") as old_val, 
          text((' || quote_literal(NEW.*) || '::"' || tg_table_schema || '"."' || tg_relname || '")."'  || each_column.column_name || '") 
         AS new_val  
          FROM "' || tg_table_schema || '"."' || tg_relname || '";' 
          LOOP 
             old_value = each_entity.old_val; 
             new_value = each_entity.new_val; 
              IF old_value != new_value THEN 
              i=i+1; 
              col_name[i]=each_column.column_name; 
              od_value[i]=old_value; 
              ne_value[i]=new_value; 
              END IF; 
          END LOOP; 
          END LOOP; 

 INSERT INTO B  
            (   

              tablename,  
             columnnames,  
            oldvalues, 
 newvalues 
           )   
 VALUES 
         (   

            tg_relname,  
            col_name, 
             od_value, 
  ne_value
             ); 
        End if; 
      RETURN NEW; 
  END; 
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Answer (score 1):

I thinks it's a good case to use [hstore extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) of PostgreSQL:

```
create or replace function history_trigger_func()
returns trigger AS
$$
begin
    insert into TableB
    select
        tg_relname,
        case when tg_op in ('UPDATE', 'INSERT') then hstore(new) end,
        case when tg_op in ('UPDATE', 'DELETE') then hstore(old) end;

    return null;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger tr_history_trigger after insert or update or delete on TableA
for each row execute procedure history_trigger_func();
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d94e2/2)</kbd>**

You can extend this further by removing columns which are not changing, or, if you're using PostgreSQL 9.3, you can use [JSON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) instead of hstore.